# Was the submarine attack genuine?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, aquaman

When King Orm (Patrick Wilson) goes to meet King Nereus (Dolph Lundgren) for the first time, they get attacked by a submarine.

The submarine shoots torpedoes at them without provocation. It is then sunk by Orm in retaliation. This event convinces Nereus that the surface world must be attacked now. Till this point he was on the fence about initiating a war. This event makes it plain that the surface world has already begun their offensive and must be answered.

However, it seems like people on the surface world aren't aware of the existence of Atlantis (or sentient sea creatures for that matter). It is something which seems to be treated as an urban legend based on the news bit involving Randall Park. This raises questions on the authenticity of the submarine attack. Was it genuinely an attack by the surface world or something staged by Orm to sway the tide in his favor?

Comment: not sure if this is relevant... but: ". Black Manta uses a craft disguised as a US Navy submarine to attack Atlantis using the stolen missiles to frame the humans" - . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League:_Throne_of_Atlantis

Comment: @padfoot But in film they steal submarine first

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was stated in film itself that Orn made Black Manta steal a submarine and then use that to stage a fake attack from humans. It was the same submarine incident where Black Manta lost his father due to Aquaman not helping him.

This discussion happen later when Orn sent gold coins to Black Manta.

Comment: I see. It seemed like the submarine got sunk with Black Manta's  father.